# In ADF Pipeline, Switch Activity Implementation

Tags: azure, copy, azure-data-factory

I want to implementing pipeline using this flow
for loop -> switch activity -> copy activity
I have three parameters one is array and remaining two are strings(might be some value or it be a empty value)

1. SourceInfoArray - array
2. SourceName - String
3. TableName - String

In Switch Activity, I want to check whether SourceName and TableName parameters values are contained in SourceInfoArray array parameter or not for sourceName and TableNames

my SourceInfoArray input string -

```
[{"SourceName":"l","Database":"a","TableName":"areamanager","Query":"select * from areamanager"},{"SourceName":"m","Database":"b","TableName":"areamanager","Query":"select * from areamanager"},{"SourceName":"n","Database":"c","TableName":"areamanager","Query":"select * from areamanager"},{"SourceName":"k","Database":"d","TableName":"areamanager","Query":"select * from areamanager"}]
```

I tried using some expressions like @equals() and @if() like that
Here switch activity excepting string type as return type because it need to match the expression value with case statement values
@equals(), @if(), etc.,

If you have any new ideas or suggestion, please reply to this question.

Comment: Hi @Ram - can you add some specific details about what you have tried and what is not working?

Comment: @Ram, what are your case names? and how many case names are there? for what condition what case should execute? provide these details.

Comment: Hi @JoelCochran,
In Switch activity, If user parameters SourceName and TableName are empty values means then I need to consider the value form this parameter SourceInfoArray.
So I used coalesce() but this coalesce() triggering for all the sources 
My expression - coalesce(pipeline().parameters.SourceName, item().SourceName)
It should trigger only one which i passed as parameter otherwise it should trigger from array parameter. If you have any suggestions or ideas please reply to this question.

Comment: The case names in switch should be added manually. Can you provide all the Case names that are required and the respective conditions for you?

Comment: Hi @RakeshGovindula, 
we are loading data from mysql to adls 
So, in adf we created 4 datasets for 4 sourceNames to access the mysql tables data.
I required 4 case statements inside case statement I kept copy activity.

for example 1 take above my SourceInfoArray input string
SourceName - sil and TableName - areamanager
only these should trigger sil case statement inside that we have sil copy activity
For Example 2 
SourceName - '' and TableName - ''
in this scenario all the sources and tablenames should run for all case statements whcih passing from this parameter SourceInfoArray.

Answer (score 0):

> we are loading data from mysql to adls So, in adf we created 4 datasets for 4 sourceNames to access the mysql tables data

**If your source tables are from same database**, then no need to create 4 datasets and 4 cases. You can use single dataset for 4 tables using dataset parameters. That means you can achieve your requirement with a single case statement.

Divide your cases like below.

1. **TableExists** - When `TableName` and `SourceName` exists in the array.
2. **TableNameEmpty** - Case when variables are empty.
3. **Default** - Case when Variables do not exist in the array.

To copy the 4 tables dynamically, first create a dataset parameter `TableName` of string type in the dataset. Here, I have used SQL dataset, you need to use your dataset.

[image]

Use this parameter in the table name of the dataset.

[image]

Now, coming to the Switch activity, give the expression like below.

```
@if(and(equals(variables('SourceName'),''),equals(variables('TableName'),'')), 'TableNameEmpty',if(and(equals(variables('SourceName'),item().SourceName),equals(variables('TableName'),item().TableName)),'TableExists','DefaultCase'))
```

[image]

This expression will check whether variables are empty or not. **If Empty**, it will give the case name `TableNameEmpty`.

So, in the case `TableNameEmpty`, you need to give your logic to copy all the tables from source to target. For sample, I have added a set variable activity.

[image]

**If the variables are not empty and exists in the array**, then it will give the case name `TableExists`.

In this case, add the copy activity with the above dataset as source. Give the variable `@variables('TableName')` to the dataset parameter like below.

[image]

If variables are not existing in the array, then it will give the `DefaultCase` as output and it will execute the activities in the default case if there are any.

**If your tables are from different databases and if you need to use 4 datasets as per your requirement**, then go with your logic. Create cases as per the table names. Give the Switch activity expression like below.

```
@if(and(equals(variables('SourceName'),''),equals(variables('TableName'),'')), '<TableName_empty_case_name>',if(and(equals(variables('SourceName'),item().SourceName),equals(variables('TableName'),item().TableName)),variables('TableName'),'DefaultCase'))
```